# Connect geny motion emulator to the internet

Tags: networking, virtualbox, internet, ip

i have an adsl modem and a broadband connection
I have set up my emulator as mentioned in this post like so:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19922077/genymotion-unable-to-start-the-genymotion-virtual-device/20018833#20018833

but i still am not able to connect to the internet

i have two adapters set up in the VM

1)the host adapter
2) as NAT but i cant figure out what adapter type is to be set for the nat

Kindly help i also tried to set up the 2nd adapter as a bridge adapter but that did not work

all i want is to connect to the internet via the emulator and also from my pc browser

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was facing the same problem of not getting connected to internet with my Genymotion installed in Ubuntu 15.04 and the virtual device that I was using was Google Nexus 5-5.1.0-API 22-1080*1920. My regular internet connection through for the desktop machine is through a cable connected broadband.

And in Virtual Box > Settings > Network > Adapter 2 > it was just the default configuration, that is "Attached To" was "NAT" and "Cable Connected" was checked.

So, after launching the virtual device Google Nexus 5-5.1.0-API 22-1080*1920 > I just went into Settings > Wi-Fi > Let it select the IP automatically > After that just click on Done > and now I am connected to internet

Comment: That didn't work for me on mac osx behind a firewall. firewall settings are correct, *WiredSSID* reports as connected, but browser times out when connecting to any web page.

Answer (score 0):

Late but I had a similar issue when running Genymotion (3.2.1) on a Windows 10 machine.

I had the Windows "Virtual Machine Platform" on as I was using WSL2. I disabled it, restarted my system and Genymotion got connected to internet.

Hope someone finds this useful.